# Explicitly defaulted special member functions with aliased type — Clang vs. GCC

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, clang++

GCC trunk (9.0) and Clang trunk (7.0) disagree on the following code:

```
template<int size_>
struct BadArray {
    static constexpr int size = size_;// GCC complains due to this indirection
    using Self = BadArray<size>;

    Self& operator=(const Self&) noexcept = default;
};
```

Compilation with GCC fails with the error message

```
error: 'BadArray<size_>::Self& BadArray<size_>::operator=(const Self&)' cannot be defaulted
```

while Clang accepts the code ([live example with GCC 8.1 and Clang 6.0](https://godbolt.org/g/KCFZN6)).

1. Is there a well-defined behavior? If yes, **which compiler is right**?
2. Is it appropriate to file a bug report for either GCC or Clang?

Comment: I would say bug with gcc. Btw changing to `using Self = BadArray;` makes it happy (injected name).

Comment: Seems like gcc doesn't recognize that `size == size_` (it gives the same error if you do like... `BadArray& operator=(int) = default;`). There are core issues about invoking `constexpr` member functions (1626 and 2335), but I don't know why this shouldn't work...

Comment: [GCC bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86646)

Comment: MSVC has the same bug then: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/M7T7bdsed